# Easiest way to replicate a picture

Tags: image

I'm trying to replicate a picture in order to replace smoke with animated smoke.

It seems simple enough: make the chimey, make a texture from the image and add the smoke and sky. But I can't help but think that there's a simpler way. I don't really manage to match the colors and smoke direction.

[image: picture to replicate]

Comment: More or less - this is the right approach. I'm not completely sure, but this photo looks like being post processed to achieve those colours.

Comment: You can achieve the smoke by applying Physics and Smoke. I think that is the correct way to animate it, I do not know it other way. If that is how you want to do it then I can show you but I cannot help you with pure textures. Which Blender are you using V2.79b or V2.80 Beta?

Comment: @cgslav Yeah, I think it is heavily edited in post. But I think the smoke should be possible in Blender with wind + smoke sim and some motion blur. Everything else I've already accomplished. At least somewhat.

Comment: @Sprad001 I used 2.80 Beta, but it's crashing so often that I'm kind of regretting it now. My biggest problem is getting the smoke to render properly. I've achieved something, but if I try to get thicker smoke, it takes forever to bake / render / whatever. I've got the chimney done now, but my smoke is really thin.

Comment: @TemporaryName, most of the time I do not have problem with 2.80 Beta. Unfortunately as you get more realistic the more tasking it is on computer power. For more smoke have you tried to increase the Surface of the smoke emitter object?

Comment: @Sprad001 In theory, I can let my PC run 24 hours to bake and render sometimes. But I'm not even able to adjust how I want the smoke because it is so difficult to work with the smoke. I'm using a squashed Icosphere right now.

Comment: @Sprad001 I just found out that a lot of my problems had to do with the smoke being inside a collision mesh. Not sure how to fix it yet, but at least I got lots more smoke now.

Comment: @TemporaryName, you could edit your original posting and include an image so we can see what the problem is. To effect how the smoke behaves, apart from its own settings, you can experiment with various Force Field that you can add to your scene with Shift+A and select one of the desired effects.